Dashboard:57 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input with Charts.Js
I'm trying to create a chart that has both a bar dataset and a line dataset. When I load the page, the model populates correctly as far as I can see, but the chart doesn't show up and the only errors or clues I have are Dashboard:57 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. I'm not sure the second error is related but thought it might help. My code for the chart is as follows:
<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
    <canvas id="ticketCountChart" width="1100" height="180"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('ticketCountChart').getContext('2d');

        var newTicketData = @Model.DashboardMetrics.HourlyTicketData;
        var resolveddData = @Model.DashboardMetrics.HourlyResolvedTicketsData;

        var labels = newTicketData.map(item => item.Hour);

        var lineBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        label: 'New Tickets',
                        data: newTicketData.map(item => item.NewTicketsCount),
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        fill: true
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Resolved Tickets',
                        data: resolvedData.map(item => item.ResolvedTicketsCount),
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Hour'
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Number of Tickets'
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Tickets Overview (Last 24 Hours)'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'bottom'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (tooltipItem) {
                                var label = tooltipItem.dataset.label || '';
                                var value = tooltipItem.raw;
                                return label + ': ' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


I've tried parsing the data to get rid of any leading zeroes and ensuring the data points are being accessed as ints, but that hasn't had any effect. Triple-checked all the options, missing parentheses etc but can't see anything wrong

System.Private.CoreLib.dll  That error looks like a .NET c# error, and nothing to do with Chart.js

@Kieth I assumed it would be but wasn't 100% sure so included it anyway. Thank you for clearing that up. I've removed it for clarity

In the code you pasted you don't close the plugins object. You may simply remove the ); on the penultimate line and leave just the closed brace }. You'll also have to use the labels in the data. Here's a fiddle for the file structure.
